# While loop skips line

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I currently have this function:

```
double GrabNumber() {
    double x;
    cin >> x;
    while (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "You can only type numbers!\nEnter the number: ";
        cin >> x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Its purpose is to check if `x` is a valid number, returning it if it is valid or repeating `cin >> x` if it is not.

It's called during this function:

```
void addition() {
    cout << "\nEnter the first number: ";
    double a = GrabNumber();
    cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    double b = GrabNumber();
// rest of code
```

When I type for example "6+" when it tells me to enter the first number, it accepts it but immediately goes to the second line and calls it an error where I haven't even entered my input.

I assume this is because the first input only accepts "6" while "+" goes to the second input returning an error. Therefore, there must be an issue with the parameters of `while`.

Comment: I think you will have to use [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) and parse complete line, instead of using `cin` like that

Comment: But Getline Reads As A String

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your input is immediately successful, you don't ignore the rest of the line, which ends up into the next input. This can be fixed by simply duplicating the `cin.ignore` call.

```
double GrabNumber() {
    double x;
    cin >> x;

    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // <--

    while (cin.fail()) {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "You can only type numbers!\nEnter the number: ";
        cin >> x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

I'll leave DRYing this code as an exercise ;)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this kind of issue, prefer using [`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) and [`stod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/):

```
double GrabNumber() {
    double x;
    bool ok = false;
    do
    {
        std::string raw;
        std::getline (std::cin, raw);
        try
        {
            x = stod(raw);
            ok = true;
        }
        catch(...)
        {}
    } while(!ok);
    return x;
}
```

In general case, it's easier to acquire raw string with `getline` and to parse it just after. In this way, you can check everything you want: number of characters, sign position, if there are only numerical character, *etc.*